# How do I temp mute someone using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a !mute command for a discord.py bot. I'd like it to be formatted like this: `!mute @user 10s`. The `s` is for seconds. I'd also like it to be able to read `m` for minutes, `h` for hours and `d` for days. And if possible, maybe even `!mute @user 1d 3h 3s`. Here's the code I have right now.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, mute_time : int):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send("{} has has been muted!" .format(member.mention))
            await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send("{} has been unmuted!" .format(member.mention))
```

It works fine as it is for the time being. It does `!mute @user 10` for 10 seconds.

I also have an unmute command. It works like this. `!unmute @user`.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send("{} has has been unmuted!" .format(member.mention))
```

Except we have a problem with this command. Let's say I execute `!mute @user 60`. If I decide to unmute them using the command `!unmute @user` before the 60 seconds are up, it unmutes them successfully. But then when the 60 seconds are up, it unmutes them again and sends the message for the second time.

Again, just to clarify, my goal is to create a !mute command so it's possible to do `!mute @user 1d 3s`. `s` is for seconds, `m` is for minutes, `h` is for hours, `d` is for days, `mo` is for months and `y` is for years.

Any answers would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After the `await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)`, you can add an if statement to see if the user has the muted role, and only if they do, then you remove the role and send the message.

Along these lines:

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, mute_time : int):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send("{} has has been muted!" .format(member.mention))
            await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
            IF USER STILL HAS MUTED ROLE:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.send("{} has been unmuted!" .format(member.mention))
```

Comment: How about the rest?

Comment: Wdym? The rest should stay the same unless I am missing something. If you used unmute before the time was up, they won't have the muted role anymore so it won't send the message again. If you didn't use unmute, they will still have muted and it will send only once.

Comment: I mean the rest of my question. I wanted to create it so it's possible to do `/mute @user 1d 3s`. `s` is for seconds, `m` is for minutes, `h` is for hours, `d` is for days, `mo` is for months and `y` is for years.

Comment: You can pass the mute_time parameter as a string and then use the `string.split()` function to split each separate time component. You'll then have a list that looks like ['1d', '2m','3s'] It'll then be up to you to iterate through those components, looking to see their value and type of time (day/minute). You can then convert that to seconds and input it into the `async.sleep` method. It will only work if you setup the function with `async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, mute_time):`. So that it takes the entire amount of time components.